# Android: Adding OnClick Handler to Custom Preference Layout

Tags: android, imagebutton, preference

I am on some unknown territory. Unfortunately, I don't fully understand how Android is structured. I am trying to create a way for users to add contacts using a preference layout. I got my app to add contact, but I am working on a way to remove the contact from the list. I created a custom layout for my preference object.

contact_pref_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title" android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:maxLines="4" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="32dp" 
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/trash_can"
        />
<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am dynamically creating the preference object everything I add a contact.

Add Contact Function:

```
   private void addContact(String contactName, String contactPhone)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"in addContact Function");

        Toast.makeText(this, contactName + "'s phone number found: " + contactPhone , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("contact_category");

        Preference newContact = new Preference(this);
        newContact.setKey("contact123");
        newContact.setTitle(contactName);
        newContact.setSummary(contactPhone);
        newContact.setLayoutResource(R.layout.contact_pref_layout);


        Log.i(TAG,"Add new Contact");
        targetCategory.addPreference(newContact);

    }
```

I am not sure where or how to add the onClickListener for the ImageButton to delete. I am not sure even sure how to delete Preference object either.
Any suggestions?

EDIT 1/26/2014 LOGCAT

```
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpleemergencywidget/com.example.simpleemergencywidget.ContactPrefActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at com.example.simpleemergencywidget.ContactPrefActivity.onCreate(ContactPrefActivity.java:36)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-26 08:22:36.846: E/AndroidRuntime(18987):    ... 11 more
```

I get this error when contactpage actvity is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using adding

```
android:onClick="deleteContact"
```

to the layout and added a deleteContact function.

Answer (score 0):

How to set the onClickListener for the ImageButton:

```
ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code that deletes the Preference object
    }
});
```

I haven't done anything with Preference objects, so I can't tell you how to delete them off the top of my noggin. That should be easy to find in the documentation though.

Comment: giving me a NullException Error at the `deleteButton.setOnClickListener...` The deleteButton is NULL therefore giving me the error. Not how to solve that issue.

Comment: Make sure you included the declaration of the ImageButton. It should go in the OnCreate method, so that it is created as soon as possible.

Comment: still null... should i make a custom preference class?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the logcat output, please? That would help me get a better idea of what is happening, because I can't see why you should be getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: went ahead and added the exception from LOGCAT